# Unable to import Ubuntu virtual machine on Centos 7 kvm host

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

```
[root@kvm ~]# virsh create /root/ns1.jesse64.xml
    error: Failed to create domain from /root/ns1.jesse64.xml
    error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-kvm: -machine pc-i440fx-trusty,accel=kvm,usb=off: Unsupported machine type
```

So I run /usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -machine ? and see

```
Supported machines are:
none                 empty machine
pc                   RHEL 7.0.0 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996) (alias of pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0)
pc-i440fx-rhel7.0.0  RHEL 7.0.0 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996) (default)
rhel6.6.0            RHEL 6.6.0 PC
rhel6.5.0            RHEL 6.5.0 PC
rhel6.4.0            RHEL 6.4.0 PC
rhel6.3.0            RHEL 6.3.0 PC
rhel6.2.0            RHEL 6.2.0 PC
rhel6.1.0            RHEL 6.1.0 PC
rhel6.0.0            RHEL 6.0.0 PC
```

So is there some package I need to install? The VM was created on a Ubuntu KVM host.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're seeing this error because Ubuntu put their own customizations into its version of libvirt and qemu/KVM. RHEL, of course, did the same thing.

But there's always a machine type that will work, namely, `pc`. This is always aliased to the latest i440fx machine type available on the hypervisor at the time the VM is defined.

Somewhere in the XML you'll find something like:

```
<type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-trusty'>hvm</type>
```

Just change this to:

```
<type arch='x86_64' machine='pc'>hvm</type>
```

(And note that if you use the new `pc-q35-xxx` machine types, the generic machine type is `q35`.)

Comment: Thanx thanx thanx!

Comment: of course on RHEL, the machine type best adjusted to run on the OS is the RHEL-7.